# Values not in primary key entered in foreign key

Tags: mysql

I am using xampp and i created realation for two tables.. i mean in first table i have a primary key and second table have a column which is referencing the primary key. when i enter a value in the second table (with id not entered in primary key), the value is entering perfectly without showing any error. how to avoid?

Comment: can you show the table structure?

Comment: post your create query of tables.. look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: i created using xampp and created the relation also in xampp